# What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This is a question that I have in mind:

[My question : Find nth smallest element in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546180/find-nth-smallest-element-in-numpy-array)

I tried to present my case in comments, but to no avail, are there other mechanisms to get my question reopened?

I believe marking a not-duplicate question as duplicate is  unfair to the answer to the question, and moreover it promotes more duplicate questions, somebody might search for my question, and not find an answer, and post their own question...and so on. Therefore, I believe there should be a good mechanism to reverse wrongly marked duplicate questions.

Edit:

I checked the profiles of people who voted to close, and none of them have high upvotes in `python` and `numpy` which are the tags of the questions, so it is quite possible that they are not fluent in those fields and missed the difference in the questions. I wonder if it is possible to have the question evaluated by python or numpy experts, i.e, people with some minimum number of upvotes in those tags.

Comment: Other mechanisms: (1) starting a discussion on Meta, as you have done, and (2) asking users in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), like in [the Python room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). **Note, however, that just because you make your case to more people, that doesn't mean that you'll persuade them either.**

Answer (score 22):

The instructions for handling this case can be found *directly below your question* after it has been closed as a duplicate:

[image: please edit this question to explain how it is different]

You may also be able to vote to reopen ([as ProgramFOX notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate/253522#253522)) or convince others to do so via comments, but everything else will be easier if you first **edit to clarify the differences**. Don't neglect the title...

Comment: What if the question is only marked as "This question may already have an answer here:" ? Their question is wrong, but it ushers folks away before they even read the question. I would love to know why the person who conflates columns with rows has editorial rights to begin with, but then to have unimpeachable powers of appraisal? Really? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848501/iterate-through-columns-in-dplyr/37867694#37867694 And this is far from the first time I have recognized this problem in the stacks.

Comment: Please just allow folks to link them. Let a quorum decide to add this questionable comment, just like you do for the final decision of duplication.

Comment: No one sees that message but the person who asked the question, @leerssej. Unless it gets closed, all other visitors just see a normal comment with a link.

Comment: Excellent, and verified by co-worker. Thank you: great to know :-D

Comment: I've just edited the question I asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969520/woocommerce-programatically-get-cart-id) but the incorrect "[duplicate]" flag is still upon it ... so I thought this method did not work ... however I've then reread @Shog9's comment and tried my link when NOT logged onto SO, and I can see that indeed that link is only there for me to see, not other SO users ... Cool - this does work, I'm changing my down vote to an up vote, with apologies.

Comment: How do you vote to reopen questions incorrectly marked as duplicate when you are not the OP? Both answers on this page seem to discuss features that are only available to the OP.

Comment: @JamesHoux You do it the same way: by clicking on the Reopen link. If you don't have it, that's because the privilege is not afforded to you. OPs get to vote to reopen their *own* questions, but otherwise 3000 reputation is required to cast reopen votes, just like close votes.

Answer (score 9):

If you believe that it is not a duplicate, then vote to reopen it by clicking on the "reopen" link next to "edit". After voting to reopen, your question will go to the [Reopen Votes queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen), and people will decide whether your question should be reopened. If four other people vote to reopen (so there are five reopen votes in total), your question will be reopened.

Comment: I did vote to reopen, and there was another vote to reopen, but then they vanished.

Comment: @Akavall: Then you can try what Cupcake said.