# How to see if on hold question has been reviewed after edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, on-hold

How do I know if my question (I do not want to link it because it will look like advertising for my question) has been reviewed. It was closed as off-topic 3 days ago and I edited it two days ago asking for whoever saw it to leave a comment. So my question is: A) How do I know if my question has been reviewed and B) Should the people who put my question on hold have explained why to me?

#### Clarification

I believe that this question is not a duplicate because this question is about to how to track the review process of your question and how the process works, whereas the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue) is about how to move your question into the review queue in the first place.

Comment: The more important part of the question for me is if I can see if it has been reviewed. Can I?

Comment: sure you can. Just check whether your edit meets criteria outlined there. As soon as these are met, your question is _guaranteed_ to be reviewed (system is purposely designed to enforce reopen review for edits like this)

Comment: I made an edit that fits the criteria 2 days ago. Can I check if it has been reviewed?

Comment: until you get to 250 rep, it would be rather cumbersome. You'd have to track reviewers listed at [reopen review stats page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats), go to their profiles and look through their review history to find a link to "your" review. After 250, it would get a bit easier since you will be able to see number of reopen votes under your question

Comment: Why is it not easier?

Comment: because there is an easy way already. One can simply wait for about two weeks and re-check the question. If it's still closed, this most likely means reviewers weren't satisfied with edit (reopen votes expire in two weeks)

Comment: I believe that this question is not asking the same thing because this is asking how the review process works whereas the other question is asking how to initiate that process.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: My question was marked too broad not duplicate

Comment: I replied to comment about [your question here, at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297394/how-to-see-if-on-hold-question-has-been-reviewed-after-edits?noredirect=1#comment209456_297394) - it was "marked duplicate"

Comment: The question that this MSO question is about was marked too broad

Comment: well regarding your question over there, regarding reload a div, I can see 3 reopen votes on it now (it takes 5 to reopen)

Comment: Thank you very much! But about this question here on MSO is not a dupe of the question it is marked as a dupe of. Should I edit to clarify this? It is not a dupe because this is about the review process and the other is about how to get your question into the review cue

Comment: if you believe it's not a dupe, you can edit as explained in that question I referred above. Consider making an effort to help reopen reviewers understand why you believe it is different: lately I've seen many reopen reviews failing because askers simply "expressed themselves" and didn't try to explain, like "it's not a duplicate"

Comment: The review of your question after your edit: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5694

Comment: How did you navigate to that page?

Comment: Since Infinite Recursion was one of the users who participated in the review, they would have the page URL in their browser history as well as a link in their own profile of their review history. The review queue itself is accessible from the top-bar after you unlock the corresponding privilege.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I know if my question has been reviewed?

I think only moderators can directly see the reviews of a post.

However, anybody with enough reputation (10k+) to access the [history of reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) can use the date of the edit as an estimate and use the title of the question to search reviews of the post.

In your case, the review completed with 3 Leave Closed votes and 3 Reopen ones.

So the review didn't reopen your question, but now it has 3 reopen votes. With two more, you will have the 5 needed to reopen.

> Should the people who put my question on hold have explained why?

Not necessarily. When somebody votes to close, must choose a reason. When the post is closed, that reason is displayed.

So you already got an explanation:

> **closed** as too broad
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If
>   this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help
>   center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please edit
>   the question.

Comment: I didn't link the review because you didn't link the question. But I can link it if you want, you will be able to see it even without review privileges.

Comment: Ok here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869384/reload-a-div-and-move-previous-content

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been placed in a review queue (the Reopen Votes queue) to be considered for reopening. This queue is accessible to users with 3K+ reputation.

---

Source [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure
>   to encourage edits and improvements to the question.
>
> If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on
>   hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be
>   considered for reopening.
>
> If it is not reopened within five days, the [on hold] notice
>   automatically changes to [closed].
>
> There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and
>   a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but
>   they both allow comments, votes and edits.

Comment: But is there a way to know if the question has been reviewed and not reopened vs it just not having been reviewed in the first place?

Comment: If the conditions above are true, it was put in the queue, and that queue is always near-empty, so it will be done fast either way.