# How to deal with askers who incorrectly claim their question is "not a duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

When a question is believed to have been wrongly closed, the [advice that is given to them is to "update your question and explain why it is different from the other"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate) (ironically, this question is closed as a duplicate of a duplicate).  But what if the question really is a duplicate?

- The OP believes the question does not apply to them (usually because they failed to narrow down the source of the problem and the question doesn't outright specify their particular use case)
- They don't understand how to apply the solution to their own code
- They didn't scroll past the selected answer to find an answer that would be more appropriate to their specific case

Example "reasons" I have seen for why the OP's question is not a duplicate of the designated question:

- "This is not a duplicate" (seriously, no reason given, just "not a duplicate")
- "I am using a loop, but that question isn't" (but the thing the OP wants to do *inside* the loop is the same)
- "That question is old" (and the technology hasn't changed since then)
- "I need to have 3 background images, but that question only shows how to do it with some other number" (or the target question explains the syntax for multiple backgrounds rather than giving something the OP can copy/paste)
- "I want to do X, and that question doesn't have a solution that lets me do X" (where X is not possible and the target question offers the only solutions that exist given that X is not possible)

In a perfect world, users who are looking through the reopen queue would see their reasoning for the BS that it is.  However, I have seen questions opened simply because the OP said "it's not a duplicate" and no further explanation given.

---

I had a different question in mind when I started writing this question, but I think a better use case has come along today:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142228/rails-4-scss-background-image-image-url-path-cant-find-image

Timeline:

- I left a comment stating that I thought it was a possible duplicate of [this CSS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106759/why-is-my-background-image-not-appearing) (I didn't want to close right away because I have a gold badge)
- OP responds with "I don't see how that's related to my problem" (automatically deleted because it referenced the dupe target question)
- I request the output of the CSS a second time so that I can be certain
- OP responds by posting a screenshot of their browser's DOM inspector
- I close it as a duplicate
- OP raises a custom flag and a moderator reopens the question
- OP does nothing to prove that the question is not a duplicate (a simple "I changed `background-image` to `background` and the problem was the same" would have sufficed)

Since the moderator in question is also a gold badge holder for one of the other tags on the question, they would have been able to reopen the question with a single vote even if they weren't a moderator.  So I don't think this is a misuse of the mod's powers.

The comments that were removed by a second mod:

- I leave a comment for the first mod asking why they reopened it
- OP responds by gloating "It was reopened because it was a duplicate" and said something to the effect of "if you're not going to be helpful, go away"
- I respond with "I'm not talking to you" and pointed out they did nothing to prove it wasn't a duplicate
- OP responds with "The proposed answer in that question will not work in a rails app in production environment. I do not appreciate your tone or attitude. As mentioned before your action was not helpful. Thank you"

My reasoning for why this is a duplicate:  by comparing the screenshot (the first image) of the OP's source code to the screenshot of the screenshot of the DOM inspector (the second image), we can see that the subject of the question (the `image-url()` function) appears to be behaving as it should (`image-url(something.jpg)` is replaced with `image-url(/path/to/something.jpg)`).  We can also see from the screenshot of the DOM inspector that the browser is unhappy about the declaration in question because it is crossed out and has a warning symbol next to it.  Depending on the browser, this can mean different things (either the property is being overwritten or it is invalid).  In this particular instance, the property has invalid values.

So the question becomes, why are we voting to reopen questions without verifying that the question is not duplicate?

Comment: Hmm, there's history we can no longer see.  Nothing good by the looks of it.  When it gets to that then the show is over, "he was mean to me" gets the edge, always.  Not *actually* a problem beyond the hurt feelings.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added a brief summary of the other comments that were removed (the actual comments weren't *that* bad).

Comment: Read question description and not only the title

Comment: @albanx Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: On the other hand, how to deal with the fastest triggers in the Old West who mark a question as a duplicate before reading it, let alone understanding it?

Comment: Do you not think that stackoverflow is *particularly bad* for spamming questions with close votes? In comparison to other exchanges? It seems to me that a lot of people skim over questions and issue close votes either because "it's not a question I want to see or am interested in answering" or because "it has [choose: some/a lot of/almost no] similarity to QUESTION XYZ which I've read before" and therefore I'll mark it as a duplicate. Sometimes I ask a question and link in another question which is very similar, but I can't fix my problem using that question. (See next comment)

Comment: (See prev. comment) Am I wrong to post that question, then? Essentially, this is a question of: Am I NOT ALLOWED to use stackexhange if someone else posted a similar question to mine, and they got an answer which fixed their problem but did NOT fix mine? If so, the guidelines should be updated to say this.

Comment: @user3728501 I'm not sure what you're getting at here.  If your question is clearly not a duplicate, then it should be reopened, but it is up to you to  *prove* that it is not a duplicate before it is reopened.  To suggest that it is fine to reopen duplicates without proof because some other questions get closed by mistake is silly.  Also, CR is probably the fastest SE site to consistently close off-topic questions (there is almost a 100% guarantee the question will be closed before you get an answer).

Comment: Is it just me, or is this clearly _not_ a duplicate of that question? In the older question, the issue was a case of adding extra unsupported properties to `background-image`, and in the question in question, the scss is not doing that. Maybe you're mistaken in closing it as a duplicate.

Comment: I think one huge problem is the term "duplicate" is greatly abused in SO terminology; if it's different at all, it's not a duplicate, so there's very rarely true duplicates. Seeing if this is discussed elsewhere on meta.

Comment: @Jacob The screenshot of the OP's DOM inspector clearly shows the generated output as `background-image: url(/images/44.jpg) repeat top center fixed;`.  The background-image property only accepts a single value, which is why the inspector has it crossed out.  Still think I was mistaken?

Comment: I saw that. It's possible they excluded relevant details in the question, making it a duplicate, but in the question, they only used `image-url`. Whether they left out details should have been determined through conversation rather than assumed. It would certainly peeve me if someone assumed my question was a duplicate of another without clear evidence. Shouldn't the burden of proof be on the one doing the closing?

Comment: The OP provided a screenshot, how is that not proof?  Yes, the OP should have copy/pasted the code and its generated output into the question.  The fact that it is a screenshot doesn't make it not proof.

Comment: What I mean is that there may be something else unexpectedly adding those additional items to the property that's specific to rails. There's a difference between "oh, well I left that out because I didn't think it was important" and "weird, where did `repeat top center fixed` come from?" I don't think the screenshot proves anything other than the fact that the generated CSS matches the duplicating question, which is different than the OP's code duplicating the question.

Comment: The OP put it there.  The OP removed the screenshot of the source in the latest edit, which was done after this question was posted.  In that screenshot it is clearly written as `background-image: image-url('/images/backgrounds/44.jpg') repeat top center fixed;`.  Ironically, the OP thought having the offending source code made the question "less clear" (see: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32142228/revisions)

Comment: Ah, that dreaded edit history. You were totally justified in calling it a duplicate! Maybe this used to be in the comments historically, but explaining why it was a duplicate could have reduced friction. Maybe the OP just didn't see the relevance (not that it justifies the rudeness).

Comment: I've seen in my short time here a distressing habit from some people of calling duplicates without thinking I reckon and no explanation at all. Happened to one of mine, and for the life of me apart from a vague similarity in the title name nothing in that so called duplicate was even remotely helpful.

Comment: occasionally the dupe hammer is wielded incorrectly, I had a question closed as a duplicate where CoffeeScript was confused with JavaScript! Even editing the question to explain how CoffeeScript is different from JavaScript and how that is relevant didn't get the decision undone - when I asked the same question again a few days later this didn't happen and I got a very good answer

Comment: *"I need to have 3 background images, but that question only shows how to do it with some other number" (or the target question explains the syntax for multiple backgrounds rather than giving something the OP can copy/paste)"* I don't think this bullet point is a duplicate.

Comment: @TylerH You don't think "how do I have 2 background images" and "how do I have 3 background images" and "how do I have 4 background images" are all the same question?  What about "how do I select every 2nd element" and "how do I select every 3rd element" and "how do I select every 4th element"?

Comment: @cimmanon A lot of questions that would fall under that bullet point are asking how to do something with a specific number of items *for particular layouts*, where answers won't work for other layouts or indeterminate numbers of items.

Answer (score 23):

Well, the only correct response from the mod would have been:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

And while they *could* then also verify whether the post is a duplicate, they don't need to and arguably shouldn't even if they have the neccessary expertise.

---

Regarding those "clarifications", you *might* add a comment that their clarification is lacking any clarification and explanation, and they should either try again to see how it *is* a duplicate, or actually clarify how and why it isn't.
If their *reason* is obviously inane and simply doesn't work, try to be patient and point out why it's inadmissible, unless that's obviously hopeless.
Don't ever reopen *just* because the OP is a moron.

Comment: Agreed. Mods should not ever reopen a question unless it is an **egregiously** bad closure, like *sniffs of voting cabal* bad closure.

Comment: I don't want to jump on the mod, since they are a user as well and I would be posing the same question if it had been reopened by anyone else.  There were other comments that got removed by another mod, including a less-than-diplomatic response to the OP's gloating where I pointed out that they did nothing to prove that it was not a duplicate.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that if you find yourself starting to get aggravated (a completely understandable response when this stuff happens), just walk away. Don't bother trying to explain anything to an OP who is uncooperative. Just make sure you are confident that you took the appropriate action and leave it at that. The most likely outcome from continuing to engage when you're not at your best is that you'll make a poor choice. (The example case is a bit different since it got reopened, but I'm speaking more to the general case.)