# Is this really a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, help-improvement

I have posted this question in stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885654/php-mysql-too-many-connections-warning

I know that reading the title you can think it is a duplicate because there are already other questions about this kind of issue.

But I have read all of them and can't fix my problem. They all give the same answer, increasing the mysql "max_connections" variable. I do it without success.

I have described all this in my question linking to the already answered question. But community users marked it as duplicate. A duplicate of the question that I have mentioned and specify that was not working for me.

**UPDATE:** I know what should I do to try reopening the question (edit the question and so on). What I really want to know if this is really considered as a duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the amount of information given, any close reason is good. There's not enough information in your question, like can you even connect after a fresh start, when does it happen, what other processes access the database, and so on. You should not have to increase max_connections to 940 (!) if you're the only one connecting, for example.

Nowhere in your question it is shown that you actually tried to understand and solve the problem, only that you found the first Google hit for the error and tried the blunt option of massively increasing the amount of allowed connections. There's also a link in that answer to a MySQL FAQ about this error. Did you read it? Did you understand it?

None of that is in your question, so any close reason is good. It is too broad, unclear and off-topic (non-reproducible). So the people voting to close as duplicate, and actually link to a helpful question about the same problem, are actually helping you.

You can edit the post to add all relevant information, which will cause it to be nominated for reopening, as explained in [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need to know