# Is a meta question about a specific duplicate question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

The comment on [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate) encourages starting a discussion on Meta about a specific duplicate question.

However I have noticed another meta question [Is this really a duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315083/is-this-really-a-duplicate-question) marked as an exact duplicate of the former.

As questions refer to completely different questions I feel they would  not be duplicates even were they asking the same question. Which is not the case: the first is of "what to do?" kind while the second is asking about the opinion on duplicity.

Comment: If two main site questions are affected by precisely the same meta issue, it is fair game to mark the corresponding Meta questions as duplicates. That said, I also don't feel the two Meta questions you mention are duplicates.

Comment: It depends on how it's phrased... If I ask a specific 'my question was duped. I disagree. How can I fix this?' then yeah it should duped of the first Q you linked. Asking 'my question is different... Do you agree?' shouldn't be duped.

Comment: Now there are **3** "duplicate" words in the title.

Answer (score 4):

If two meta questions refer to two *different* duplicates, they aren't duplicates (in general).

Distinguishing these two meta questions by using different titles and mentioning the dupe is recommended.