# What is the appropriate action to take when something is seemingly wrongfully closed?

Tags: support, flags

There is a question recently posted by a user at this url:

[parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-echo-t-echo-in-c-xampp-htdocs-welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616190/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-echo-t-echo-in-c-xampp-htdocs-welcome)

Which, after being open for a while, was closed as a duplicate (I believe wrongfully).

Once it was closed, I reviewed the answer that it was marked as a duplicate for, but there was no solution on the page for this specific issue.
I believe it was closed because the titles were similar, as the question that was marked a duplicate has the same error code that the linked question did, but the linked question did not have a solution after walking through all the steps to fix it.

I've never been in this situation before, so, as I thought this was not correct, I flagged the question for moderator review with the statement:

> I don't believe this should be closed as a duplicate, as the attached
>   question may mention the error in this post, but it does not offer a
>   solution. None of the answers on the page for this specific error
>   match this scenario.

The next day I went to flag something and I got a message that says:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please
>   review them before flagging this post!

So I checked my flags, and under the flag that I posted, it says

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention

---

First of all I want to apologize if this is not the correct use of the flag, but I had 2 specific questions about it.

1. What is the appropriate course of action in this situation?
2. What are some examples of when using this flag is appropriate?

Comment: take a step back and consider the possibility that you are incorrect. If you then still feel you aren't, cast your reopen vote if you have that privilege, or move on.

Comment: @KevinB Incorrect about what? That it isn't a duplicate?

Comment: It's usually the OP of the post that needs to take action if they disagree with their question being put on hold/closed. In the case of being flagged as a duplicate, they need to edit their post to demonstrate why the duplicate does not solve their issue.

Comment: @BSMP But the post has enough information, because walking through the solutions on the linked answer didn't solve the issue. The linked answer contains answers like "this may be the issue, try this", but none of them relate to the question.

Comment: An example of a correct use of a moderator intervention flag would be flagging a post for plagiarism or flagging a post that has suspicious voting activity. Basically, flag for moderator attention for situations the community can't handle themselves.

Comment: *walking through the solutions on the linked answer didn't solve the issue* - Then the OP should edit that information into their question. If it's true then that should get their question re-opened when it goes into the re-open queue. Let the OP make this change themselves though; they only get one shot at getting their question re-opened so let them improve it as much as possible in one edit.

Comment: @BSMP Thank you, that clears up my 2nd question. I still disagree that it should have ever been closed though, the only answer on the page that _could_ even be the answer, states that it may just be a missing semi-colon in the statement before the error, which takes a few seconds to see that answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Note that they shouldn't edit the post to say *that* the duplicate post doesn't answer their question, rather, they should edit the post to describe *how* it fails to answer the question; explaining how they applied the solution to their situation (or why they couldn't), what happened as a result, and how that failed to work.

Comment: @Servy that's my point, _there isn't a solution on the page for the question_, all of the solutions are completely irrelevant to the code in the question that was marked as a duplicate. The OP of the post even stated they had read that same answer the _day prior_ before making his question, but none of the solutions on the page were relevant to his code

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton And again, just *stating* that they're irrelevant isn't helpful.  One needs to explain *how* they fail to solve the problem.  The question itself is also *really* bad, just dumping a ton of code and saying it doesn't compile.  Personally I'd just rather see it closed for not properly describing the problem than as a duplicate.

Comment: The error is a syntax/copy-paste error. an answer to this question won't be useful to other users who may end up with the same error message (you can find dozens of instances of people asking this very same question with various different ways of it occurring, all of which are syntax errors or invis characters.) Pointing the user to a question that explains how to debug syntax errors is far more useful than pointing them to a question with the same error message but potentially a different problem.

Comment: @Servy I believe that the question is full, that is all of the relevant code, and there are no syntax issues that I could find, and he tried to find before posting his question. He was at a loss, and even with all the code there I am at a loss too. You can tell within seconds of looking at the linked answer that it isn't relevant, as there are 4 answers as part of the post. 1 is saying to check for a semicolon on the line before the error, which is a syntax error and would be closed anyways, but that's not the issue. The other 3 answers are irrelevant because OP doesn't use classes ...

Comment: @Servy reserved words, OR "Statements in expression context"

Comment: @KevinB yeah I'm not so much arguing the fact it should be closed, but that the attached duplicate is not correct. I wasn't aware of another duplicate question either however for these invis characters etc. I didn't see any syntax issues in the code, and the same code works on other servers

Comment: just search for the error message, there's so many of this specific one. but the chosen question would potentially fix all of them.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton No, just dumping a pile of code and saying, "it doesn't work" is not a good question. There's even a specific close reason for exactly that behavior.  That the OP was at a loss for how to even state what their error was (rather than that they have one) doesn't make the question any more appropriate for the site.  All they said was that they have a syntax error, so they got directed to a post that tells them how to fix syntax errors.  If they ask a better question that actually explains what the problem is, they could get a better answer.

Comment: @Servy Okay, I agree with you in the aspect that the question could have been asked better. But that doesn't forgive linking to unrelated questions as a duplicate

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It's not unrelated.  The question asked how to fix syntax errors, it got linked to a question on how to fix syntax errors.  If the question asks a better question, it can get a better answer.

Comment: I agree with you that linking to an unrelated question is wrong... i just disagree that that is what happened in this case.

Comment: Moderator flags should not be used to get a question re-opened. That's something for the community to handle. We are not going to unilaterally overrule votes cast by the community unless it's something *really* egregious. This wasn't. I even asked a PHP expert to take a look at it before I dismissed your flag, just to make sure I wasn't missing anything, since I don't know PHP. I wasn't. They thought the closure was valid. As for what you should do, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476, among others.

Comment: It look more like a problem that can no longer be reproduced - The syntax looks fine and should work (Unless I missed anything of course), so that's why I won't vote to reopen - It would only to VTC for another reason. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45616190/edit) that post, try adding more details, explain why it's not duplicate, respond to the comments left there and let the community do decide - Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you @CodyGray for the references. I wanted to ask this question so I could become a better community member, and now that I know how to handle these situations, I can do so accordingly :)

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree with what you said about "can no longer be reproduced", but then that is what it should be closed as

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the appropriate course of action in this situation?

Make a post here (on Meta), tag it with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)[vote-to-reopen](/questions/tagged/vote-to-reopen), and have **a *very*  strong argument as to why the post should be reopened at all.**  This current question lacks that argument, so I'm going to lean on the expertise of the gold badge holder who deemed it to be a dupe.

> What are some examples of when using this flag is appropriate?

**Only flag the moderators when there is something that the community can't handle.**  We can handle reopening things just fine, and we don't need their help with that.  Where we *would* need their help would be if you suspect that there's some foul play going on with the accounts (i.e. sockpuppets boosting one another), or if the post had contained sensitive credentials (a flag would at most get it to the people that could remove it from history).