# Do not see edit option on a question marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773698/installing-mysql2-gem-errors) which was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888681/in-my-rails-3-app-simple-captcha-doesnt-display-image-on-production-mode). From what I understand, the dup is not related to this question and should not be marked as such.

I checked the answers mentioned here - [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate) but I do not see the option to edit the question to reopen.

[image]

I marked the question for moderator intervention and mentioned the appropriate reason but that [flag was declined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2651076?group=1&status=3) with the reason `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`

What should have been my correct course of action in this case?

Comment: @ayhan If so, then how should I mark the question as not a duplicate?

Comment: You shouldn't. You need 3k of reputation to re-open vote, which I just did (and posted an request in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42093529#42093529)). It is a bit silly to edit that post to explain why it is not a duplicate as you litteraly have to edit in (and that edit needs to be approved by 2 reviewers, so **DO NOT** try this): *captcha is not mentioned once in my question and mysql isn't mentioned once in the duplicate, how on earth can they be duplicates*

Comment: @rene great! Does that I mean that unless I have a 3k reputation, there is nothing I can do about such a scenario? If I see no direct action I could take, I thought flagging for moderator attention was the way to go, and that was declined

Comment: Related: [Ask a new question if not a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327202)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The text of [the original duplicate notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT5c5.png) has been changed. The old guidance was to edit or ask a new question. In most cases, no such guidance is given, probably because that advice was often taken as

> Edit my question to say "This isn't a duplicate!!!111"

A lot of times people won't apply principles from the duplicate to their problem and they want a hand-held answer. An edit won't fix that.

Understand that your own image shows the ability to edit is still there (the `edit` link is under the tags), it's just not a recommended course of action anymore.

Moderators don't handle close/reopen very often (outside of the obvious problems like spam), so you should expect mods to decline any flag that requires a more specific tag knowledge. Close/reopen is left more to regular users with high rep, especially in cases of duplicates.

As rene noted, don't try to suggest an edit for why this isn't a duplicate if you can't directly edit the question (edits normally throw a question into the Reopen queue). If you feel it's been duped in error **and you are not the OP**, I would leave a comment and then post on Meta about it. Meta is a good place to escalate things you cannot do yourself.

Comment: If you feel it's been duped in error and you are not the OP, I would vote to re-open, leave a comment and then *not* post on Meta about it. Overloading meta with isolated cases that don't indicate abuse, and don't particularly cause much damage doesn't feel very constructive. If OP feels the need, they can post it here.

Comment: @GolezTrol Remember, the OP cannot cast reopen votes yet. Or are you saying people with >3k rep shouldn't be able to reopen questions?

Comment: I'm saying exactly the opposite. I think posting individual cases to Meta should not be done lightly. OP can post on Meta if they think it's wrong. If you're not OP, you can leave a comment and vote to re-open it (if you are >3k, otherwise just comment). But if you're not OP, why would you take matters in your hand by alerting Meta about this? Such an alert has quite an impact, and it feels to me like bystanders can't judge well enough whether that's worth it. Maybe OP has left, is re-writing the question, or will post to Meta himself, so don't make that decision for them.

Comment: Also, owners of binding dupe close votes can be pinged on questions, so disputes can directly be addressed to the people who hammered a given dupe.