# Duplicate question process is conceptually untenable

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

If a user asks a question and someone with a ton of rep comes along, thinking it's already been asked, they usually flag the question and close it. I don't know the exact stats on this but I would say that 90% of the time or greater, they are not allowed the option (Which does exist) to click "This is indeed a duplicate" or "It's actually not a duplicate."

The person asking the question should, by default and regardless of rep, have a chance to confirm or deny the "Charge" as it were. The person asking the question is best suited to examine the charge of a duplicate as they're the ones actively working the problem.

Comment: 2 scenarios where the OP don't have a say: a)3 ppl agree on the closure b) the duplicate is suggested by someone with a gold badge (read *good experience*) in the tag(s) the question is in. As for them deciding 100% of the time...... No. The whole intent of duplicates is 'adapt this answer, it'll work for you'.Stack was never intended to rewrite how to fix an NPE 20 000 times. We'll point you to the best resource for fixing NPEs instead. The OPs aren't the best candidates to determine that, all the time (at least not considering what is SO's goal and mission)

Comment: After closure, if you find the dupe does not resolve your issue, edit your question and clearly explain why the answers on the dupe are not helpful in your case. The question will be pushed into the reopen queue, where other users can cast votes to reopen the question. You can also ping the close-voters and ask them to revisit your question (**after you perform the aforementioned edits**), although they are in no way obliged to respond.

Comment: @yivi This process is unclear to the user. Also, one should not have to edit their post if it was in actuality fine to begin with. Dupes should prompt a question to the OP by default. Judging by the downvotes, people don't want their power curtailed. Gold badges and 3 votes are still no substitute for the person who is digging at the problem (It tends to be gold badges I believe)

Comment: As you wish. If you do not want to work with the system, and instead choose to believe it’s a matter of users being “power hungry” or something like that, you can.

Comment: To be against requiring that the OP have the option to respond has an obvious origin.

Comment: Not wanting to have to deal with it and/or want to skim through posts, flagging. It's obvious that if I post a complex problem and 3 minutes later it's flagged, the gold user has not actually worked through the problem. They do a search, think they know best, and flag the post.

Comment: Regarding "The person asking the question is best suited to examine the charge of a duplicate as they're the ones actively working the problem." -- then this site would again be flooded by basic concept questions, such as NullPointerExceptions, because the poster doesn't yet understand language rudiments to understand the canonical answer. This isn't the purpose of the site and would clutter the site needlessly with too much chaff to be able to find the wheat. No, the current system is not perfect, but it is much better than prior set-up.

Comment: @xendi "*It's obvious that if I post a complex problem and 3 minutes later it's flagged, the gold user has not actually worked through the problem.*" you might be surprised how often some complex topics come up on some tags. And a gold badge user has, by definition, *a lot* of experience with the tag in question. And I mean literally reading, understanding, and solving questions on SO. A gold badge holder don't need to have written a book on the topic but by the time they get that badge, they would have a lot of experience with solving common and uncommon questions on SO.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels just to add to that - we *already* have users disputing "that's not a dupe" because...they literally the only difference between a proposed dupe and their question is variable names. Or maybe the proposed dupe has an answer that does the exact string manipulation that's needed but then uses `.toUpperCase()` yet the asker wants lowercased string. So, we already know that the question askers aren't the best when it comes to determining what is and isn't a solution to their problem.

Comment: 90% is low-balling it, I think it is closer to ~97% of questions askers that don't follow up.  Exactly why is murkier, hard to unravel the mix of "oops, yes" and "it didn't matter that much".  But finding blame is never hard.

Comment: Your rhetoric seems to be implying that having a question marked as a duplicate is somehow *bad*. You literally say it is a "charge", and you act as if one's reaction should be to avoid having their question marked as a duplicate at all costs. That is utterly untrue. Having a question marked as a duplicate just means "this question has already been asked, and has an answer here". Is the claim sometimes wrong, and what is referenced *not*, in fact, the answer to the question? Sure. Just as sometimes wrong answers are posted. But you aren't mad about that. Experts are trusted to answer.

Comment: See also: [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not-or-what-ca), which seems to address all of your concerns.

Comment: I don’t get why you are so hung up about duplicates. Out of 120 questions you asked that are still public (so ignoring deleted posts) only [6 are closed as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a1390723%20duplicate%3ayes). One you yourself confirmed, 2 were closed outright by experts in their fields, the rest took between 2 and 4 community member votes (with a gold badge holder as 2nd or 4th vote sealing the deal).

Comment: If I also look at deleted questions the number of duplicates rises to 7, but there are 11 closed questions closed for other reasons. And 154 questions that are not closed (as duplicates or otherwise) although some of these are deleted. That means a *tiny* number of your posts were ever closed as duplicates with a single vote: 2 out of 175 questions you posted.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553894/mysql-use-result-of-select-in-or-clause) on querying a tree structure (posts and replies) was closed by Bill Karwin (a *veteran* expert in SQL) as a duplicate of the caconical post on writing tree structure queries. It absolutely answers your question; Ankit’s answer to your question is basically Bill Karwin’s query in the dupe. You certainly didn’t argue against this closure, not in the comments nor elsewhere.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349616/shell-script-unexpected-operator-for-ne) is essentially an error in trying to use bash-specific syntax in `sh` (a common mistake), so was closed to a question explaining the differences; Triplee’s answer there has a summary that includes `[[` not being available and a link to a complete overview, which includes the `$EUID` variable that bash sets but what doesn’t.

Comment: Every other duplicate has the exact answer in the target post too, so *none of these duplicates were closed in error*, and only for one did you protest the closure (the sh post above) but then admitted defeat and switched to bash. You were not an expert there and didn’t realise the experts were in fact correct. You would have incorrectly held of closure. **Nowhere here did the experts get it wrong**.

Comment: see also: [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521/839601)

Answer (score 12):

There are a lot of misunderstandings about the way the system is working here.

> thinking it's already been asked, they usually flag the question and close it

In order to mark a question as a duplicate, there must be a suggested duplicate target, so a user cannot simply just call it a duplicate without any basis. Moreover, for gold tag badge holders in the question's tag, [their close vote is binding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/178816) and will immediately close the question; this also requires a duplicate target.

My point is, it isn't just a casual thought, it is an evidenced situation. As well, many users actually put more time into researching the duplicate target than the asker did actually crafting their question.

> 90% of the time or greater, they are not allowed the option (Which does exist) to click "This is indeed a duplicate" or "It's actually not a duplicate."

This is a bogus statistic.

The OP is allowed the option to confirm if the post is a duplicate, which was a feature implemented in 2015: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes). In addition, gold tag badge holders who disagree with duplicate closure can reopen with a single binding vote.

A large problem here is that to contest the "charge" of being a duplicate, users are expected to respond in comments and edit their question. However, most users who ask duplicate questions are *not* attentive, do not respond to comments, and do not edit their post to differentiate it.

> The person asking the question is best suited to examine the charge of a duplicate as they're the ones actively working the problem.

Sometimes... Sure, maybe. Often though, the asker is unfamiliar with the technology, hence asking the question and making them rather unlikely to be the predominant source of knowledge for that topic. It is also unusual for higher rep users who ask questions to actually ask duplicate questions, which is to say that newer users are unfamiliar with the overall process here and tend to not find posts prior to posting ( arguably this is a failure of the system, which is in the process of being worked on and should be fixed in 4-6 decades ).

Comment: *4-6* ... are we getting optimistic?

Comment: @rene - The ol' 6-8 was feeling a little bit slow, to be honest. This should be much faster :D