# What to do about this special dup: BASH script vs BASH include

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

Both questions ask whether we need Shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`)

**[This is a proposed dup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615430/do-you-need-shebang-in-all-bash-scripts) about a BASH `source` (include) script**

- Proper answer: Allowed, but professional answer is 'NO'
- This is the answer I need.

**[Proposed main Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165808/should-i-use-a-shebang-with-bash-scripts) is about *all* BASH scripts, nothing about `source` (include)**

- Proper answer: 'ALWAYS'
- This is true, but it seems obvious to me
- The answer I need (above) is not given here

If this is a duplicate, then it has the wrong duplicate listed.

**It's not my question.**

**Does anyone else think I'm right and should take action to try and have it re-opened?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It does a little, but I like the comment that [starting a meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate#comment14153_253521) discussion (which I have done) is another acceptable mechanism. So, that basically says I'm right to post this on the SO meta.

Comment: Meta discussions are not guaranteed to work out in a positive way though. It is in your own best interest to rely on vetted existing meta posts first and foremost and only create a meta discussion when you have further things that are unclear.

Comment: @Gimby Do you think I should take action to re-open it? Or, do you think it is properly closed as a dup?

Comment: Although we *generally* close these as duplicates of [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252), as you note, starting a new Meta discussion about a specific Q&A is acceptable. However, when doing so, we generally expect a bit more detailed and nuanced discussion than what you provide here, which is little more than "it is not a duplicate because it didn't answer my question". Although I would not consider myself to be a shell-scripting expert, I feel like the answer you are searching for *is* clearly stated/provided by the "main" Q&A.

Comment: @CodyGray That really helps. I edited it accordingly. Do you see more how I may have a point? At least, if I'm wrong, I hope others can know enough to tell me why.

Comment: So, it sounds like you think the answer to the main Q&A needs to be edited to include a specific mention of scripts that are intended to be sourced. That would improve the overall quality and usefulness of that Q&A, and it would address this secondary issue, too.

Comment: @CodyGray Or, I could just make my own answer on the main Q&A. The trouble I have with editing the main Q is that it already has so many answers targeting that issue specifically. And, the difference really does matter. Sometimes we absolutely need the 'shebang', other times we absolutely do not. These are completely different matters that users will search for. So, I'm going to add an answer to the main. Do you think that is acceptable on SO?

Answer (score 4):

## Post appropriate answer on main Q&A

The best solution in this situation was to post a new answer on the main Q&A so that the matter duplicated in the proposed dup was addressed there also.

The answer did need to also address the main Q&A's quesiton, which was different from the proposed dup. So, that answer would not work on the proposed dup either because it addressed a different lay of the land.