# Would it be better to provide an explanation when closing questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930035/combining-geom-smooth-with-geom-label-repel) is closed as a duplicate, with no explanation. The linked answers did not help me solve the problem.

In my experience, too many questions are simply dismissed as duplicates. In this case, the person involved seemingly suggested I delete my question. I believe many 'duplicates', whether real or not real duplicates, help people find information.

Comment: I don't see where anyone suggested you delete it. It's not blocked.

Comment: I can't find any comment (even deleted) saying that you should delete the question.

Comment: "*how easily one might provoke aggressive answers at SO*" I am not sure what you are referring to, but if you see an aggressive response, flag for moderator attention and we will delete it.

Comment: The correct thing to do, if your question is *closed* as a duplicate ("blocked" sounds like you're trying to ask a question and hitting some kind of barrier, error, or restriction) is to edit it, and explain *why* it isn't a duplicate. Stating "It isn't a duplicate" isn't an explanation; put concise and clear reasoning as to why it isn't. If it was closed unilaterally by a "gold badger" you can then ping them in the comments of the question to let them know you've edited the question to explain why it's not a duplicate; many of those badgers will then be happy to reopen the question.

Comment: The person who hammered the question as a duplicate is not anonymous, but it may be hidden from view because you should not be focused on who did it, but on clarifying your question. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: FWIW, this meta question is *much* more likely to be productive if you avoid implying or alleging motivations of other people. If you highjack your own legitimate request with a soapbox for your opinion on closure, do not be surprised if others jump on the bandwagon but disagree.

Comment: Duplicates are not bad. They serve as signposts. See the FAQ ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252)

Comment: "*I believe many 'duplicates', whether real or not real duplicates, help people find information.*" this is literally the purpose of duplicates. To serve as sign posts for one canonical list of answers, rather than leaving all solutions scattered all over the place and harder to find.

Comment: @Dharman / Kevin B the _system_ recommends you delete your question [screenshot from one of my posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfM2nl.png) / [Screenshot with edit and delete options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEqlbl.png). It’s quite possible to misunderstand that (since this is part of the close banner) the user(s) who closed the question were also encouraging its deletion.

Comment: Of course the system is to blame for making inappropriate comments to the OP.

Comment: The action by the person gave me a window with two options: edit the comment so it is no longer a duplicate or delete it. 

I read that as the person knowing that these are the two options I would receive.

Comment: @VLAZ So why did SO seemingly suggest I edit the question or delete it? Sorry, but to me that’s confusing?

Comment: It gives you the *option* to edit or delete it. I'd assume the voter didn't know it'd even have a delete link, given that people who can close vote rarely ever see the version of the dialog that you see. all I see is a large edit button.

Comment: @Dharman Sorry, scared by previous experience. :-) I’m merely a social scientist, not a programmer.

Comment: If someone feels that their question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate, they should follow the advice in the linked FAQ post. Otherwise, we really don't have to explain other close votes, so I don't see why we should have to explain this one.

Comment: I'll meet this one not halfway but say a quarter way - I have had a need to want to add some kind of explanation because a duplicate link might imply one specific answer among many and you can't dupe link to an answer. So I just kind of abuse the comment system in such cases. You have to deal with what you've got.

Answer (score 15):

Providing an explanation when closing a question as a duplicate isn't a good idea. If one needs to explain why the question is a duplicate then maybe the question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate. The purpose of linking questions is to drive traffic towards existing solutions.

It's also possible that it's obvious to everyone how the linked answers provide a solution to the new question, but the question asker disagrees. In this situation, it's the responsibility of the question asker to convince readers that the proposed solution doesn't apply to the question. The author should clarify the question and submit for review. It might get reopened and new answers be provided that are specific to the new question.

Answer (score -10):

Yes, it is often better to dupe close *and* provide an explanation. Only rarely is a duplicate a 1:1 copy and it is necessary to translate some small parts between duplicate and target. Adding a small explanation in the spirit of "Your X is actually a Y and you can use it as shown in the other Q&A to get the Z you want." is often helpful.
A comment is perfectly adequate for that.

That said, while a dupe closure and explanation is better than just a dupe closure, just a dupe closure is still better than no dupe closure<sup>1</sup>. Preventing valid dupe closures by *forcing* people to spend extra time on explanations is likely harmful. Duplicate closure is already a very time intensive and thankless task.

---

<sup>1</sup>Provided that the duplicate target fits.